# AngularJS - PHP doesn't return values

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phpstorm

I've recently decided to learn AngularJS and I'm currently trying to make a simple website with PhpStorm. I have stumbled upon a problem I don't seem to be able to solve.

This is the code of the website so far.

**view.html**

```
<button ng-click="doClick()">Click</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items track by $index">
        <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.condition }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**view.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view', {
            templateUrl: 'view/view.html',
            controller: 'ViewCtrl'
        });
    }])

    .controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.doClick = function() {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'view/view.php'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.items = response.data;
                })
            };
        }
    ]);
```

**view.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $output = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}

else {
    echo "No Results";
}
?>
```

I would like to get the values from my variable `$output`. However, once I run the PHP code it only returns the whole code. It doesn't seem to recognise my PHP file as code in PhpStorm but runs just fine when accessing it through `"localhost/view.php"`.

I've tried solutions from similar threads but with no luck so far. I'm using Apache and MySQL, if that is somehow important. Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: use http://localhost/view.php instead of view/view.php in your angular controller

Comment: To add to @Ayaou comment - you need to run the site via your localhost install, which is typically at http://localhost - if you want to use a different url (such as http://view), you'll need to edit your virtual hosts file (but it's simpler if you just run it at http://localhost)

Comment: What do you mean by *"It doesn't seem to recognise my PHP file as code in PhpStorm ..."* ? What URL do you see in the browser when it does not work? What browser's Dev Tools say about URL that gets called?

Comment: Changing the path to "http://localhost/view.php" solved the problem. Now I feel like a newbie. Thank you, guys :)

Comment: @Layzone - It returned 'data: <?php [all my code] ?> instead of 'data: [Object, Object, Object, ...].

Comment: @cale_b My comment helped him,  and that's what is important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I changed the URL inside my function from

```
url: 'view/view.php'
```

to

```
url: 'localhost/view.php'
```

the PHP file worked as intended. As a side note, the PHP file was inside my project folder at first and I moved it to my Apache deployment folder to make it work. I hope this answer is understandable. Thank you **@Ayaou** for helping me out here!